# Obtain a point in a circumference

Tags: geometry

first of all sorry for my bad english. I have the center of a circumference, its radius, and a point inside the circumference. I need to obtain the point in the arc of the circumference that is cutted by the rect of the Center and the Point. I hope that the image helps:
[image: problem]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a purely algebraic point of view, you have the equation of the circle $$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=r^2$$ and the equation of the line $$y=\frac{ {y_2}-{y_1}}{{x_2}-{x_1}}x-\frac{{x_2}
   {y_1}-{x_1} {y_2}}{{x_1}-{x_2}}$$ If you replace $y$ as a function of $x$ from the equation of the line, you have a quadratic equation to solve for $x$. The solutions for $x$ are $$x=x_1 \pm\frac{r ({x_1}-{x_2})}{\sqrt{
   \left(({x_1}-{x_2})^2+({y_1}-{y_2})^2\right)}}$$ I let you computing the value of corresponding $y$'s. For sure, you must select the point on the circle which is the closest to point $P$.

Answer (score 0):

The vector $\vec{v}=\vec{CP}=\langle x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1\rangle$ can be scaled to length $r$ to obtain $\vec{w}=\frac{r}{||\vec{v}||}\vec{v}$.  Then your point $X$ on the circumference will be $C+\vec{w}$.